# Why does Python ''in operator'' return 'True' for float 1.0 if only the int 1 is a list item in [1, 2.3, 'blabla']?

Tags: python, list

In Python 3.8.5 Shell on Linux, I have a list named "mixedlist" (see below) that contains an integer, a floating point, and a string.
As we can see, the integer 1 is contained in ''mixedlist'', whereas the number 1.1 is not. So far so good. What I don't understand: oddly, Python also returns 'True' for the floating point number 1.0 , even though the list only contains an integer 1. I assume this is not a bug but a feature. But if this is the expected behaviour, could someone point out why it makes sense?

```
>>> mixedlist = [1, 2.3, 'blabla']
>>> type(mixedlist[0])
<class 'int'>
>>> type(mixedlist[1])
<class 'float'>
>>> type(mixedlist[2])
<class 'str'>
>>> 1 in mixedlist
True
>>> 1.0 in mixedlist
True
>>> 1.1 in mixedlist
False
>>> 'blabla' in mixedlist
True
```

Comment: I just noticed that `1.0 == 1` is `True`. Maybe that's related?

Comment: It makes sense because `1 == 1.0`...

Comment: you'll be more amazed to see: `True in [1, 2]` will also return `True`

Comment: `a in b` is basically something like `any(a is value or a == value for value in b)` - `1.0 is not 1`, but `1.0 == 1`.

Comment: Because `1.0 == 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `in` does the `==` comparison, and `1 == 1.0` is `True`, while `1 == 1.1`, `2.3 == 1.1`, `'blabla' == 1.1` are all `False`.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you for adding the reference!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes perfect sense now!